# Application Performance Monitoring Tool Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, monitoring

Please suggest an Application performance tool for Spring boot, I am using Jamon API right now but I need the logs at very granular level like graph and all instead of AVG, Min, MAX time only. I don't want to deploy it as additional service, I am looking something integrated within Micro service (Via Maven or Jar). Thanks in advance.

```
<Monitor> monitorName = <MonitorFactory>.start("Function Name");
//Some code here
monitorName.stop();
```

What I need is EveryDetails for this function name : Every Time Stamp it invoked, how much time this function took at that timestamp.

Comment: Maybe https://micrometer.io/ could help you? It is default application metrics collector in Spring Boot 2 https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to monitor just java methods. If that is the case then Automon should work.

JAMon has lots of modules that monitor web hits, jdbc, garbage collector, and more. Automon doesn't do all that, but can monitor any java code (even 3rd party libraries) with a simple configuration file. Automon doesn't actually do the monitoring, but instead calls any monitoring code that either you provide and out of the box it works with well-known monitoring libraries (i.e. JAMon, JavaSimon, Yammer Metrics, new relic, StatsD, Micrometer).  It is also easy to implement your own callback code that would log (using sl4j, log4j etc). In fact, a similar example referenced below does just that with calls to System.out.println.  You could even have it both log messages and call jamon.

- automon - https://github.com/stevensouza/automon
- automon System.out.println implementation - https://github.com/stevensouza/automon/blob/master/automon/src/main/java/org/automon/implementations/SysOut.java

Here is sample output using SysOut, however if you implement it you could add anything else you want.

```
    SysOut.start(..): execution(String com.stevesouza.helloworld.HelloWorld.getLastName())
    SysOut.stop(..) ms.: 0
```

Full disclosure. I wrote both JAMon and Automon.